# Nextjs/postcss css variables not available in production (Zeit)

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, postcss, css-variables

I have a series of variables defining a dark mode theme.
When running the app locally those variables are perfectly loaded.

This is the css inspector:

```
dark-mode {
  --color-bg-bg: #100818;
  --color-bg-primary: #100818;
  --color-bg-secondary: #1e1528;
  --color-bg-almost-primary: rgba(15,8,24,0.8);
  --color-bg-light: #0e0917;
}
```

But if I build the app for production or I deploy it in Zeist those variables are not available.

I thought enabling the `custom-properties` feature would fix the problem but it doesn't. This is my postcss config file:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'tailwindcss',
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? [
        '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss',
        {
          content: [
            './pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
            './components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
          ],
          defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
          features: {
            'custom-properties': true,
          },
        },
      ]
      : undefined,
    'postcss-preset-env',
  ],
};
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about zeit, but variables declared in global css are very much accessible from the `.module.css` files in both dev and production version.